# Hierarchical Graph in Neo4J from csv

Tags: python, neo4j

I have a csv as follows:

```
City State  Country
A     WB      BAN
B     WB      BAN
C     MA      BAN
D     MA      BAN
E     RG      BAN
```

Another file has citywise sales. I have to compute sales for city,region,state interchangeably in python depending on user request. Can I represent these in Neo4j and access sales from a single function in python which automatically takes city, state or region as required?

The city sales data is as follows:

```
City  Period   Sales_Amt($)
A      May17    $5
B      May17    $10
C      May17    $15
D      May17    $5
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the city sales data? And Neo4J is mostly used to represent relationship between entities, what kind of relationship do you want to represent?

Comment: Hi Tiba,
The city sales data is uploaded in question. The relationship I want to present is hierarchical - some cities go into a state and some states go into country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load of the data (using LOAD CSV for example) could look like this :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///hierarchy.csv' as line fieldterminator ','
MERGE (c:Country {id: line.countryId})
MERGE (s:State {id: line.stateId})
MERGE (ci:City {id: line.cityId})
MERGE (c)-[:HAS_STATE]->(s)
MERGE (s)-[:HAS_CITY]->(ci);
```

The load of the sales data could look like this :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///sales.csv' as line fieldterminator ','
MATCH (ci:City {id: line.cityId})
CREATE (s:Sale {period: line.period, amount: toFloat(line.amount)})
MERGE(ci)-[:HAS_SALE]->(s);
```

Now, you will have to build-up the query depending on what the entrypoint (country, state, city) is :

```
MATCH (c:Country {id: "theinputforcountry})-[:HAS_STATE]->(s:State)-[:HAS_CITY]->(ci:City)-[:HAS_SALE]->(s:Sale)
RETURN c.id, sum(s.amount);
```

or

```
MATCH (s:State {id: "theinputforstate"})-[:HAS_CITY]->(ci:City)-[:HAS_SALE]->(s:Sale)
RETURN s.id, sum(s.amount);
```

or

```
MATCH (ci:City {id: "theinputforcity"})-[:HAS_SALE]->(s:Sale)
RETURN ci.id, sum(s.amount);
```

Hope this helps !

Regards,
Tom

P.S. It is possible to walk a variable length path (so you don't have to specify the whole path) and it is also possible to turn this into a more general query that would just differ on the WHERE and RETURN clause (the WHERE would have the key you get as input, the RETURN would then group on the level that you got as input) ... but both approaches make it less clear what you are trying to accomplish (imo :-).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot Tom. I have bookmarked this answer!
Just to add for help of others: What I did after following Tom's steps was:

`MATCH (m)<-[*1..3]-(n:City) WHERE m.id=<str> return distinct n.id`
(replace str with state, city or country or whatever) --> this will return all city ids and I can also use to calculate sales data through s.sum()